# There are no positive dimensional compact submanifolds in $\mathbb C^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, complex-geometry

I've actually a problem understanding this assertion:

There no compact complex submanifolds of $\mathbb{C}^n$ of positive dimension.

This assertion is given as a corollary of the following theorem:

Let $X$ be a connected compact complex manifold and let $f \in \mathcal{O}(X)$. Then $f$ is constant.

I don't see how this theorem should imply the first assertion I wrote. The book I am reading sketches the proof of the first assertion I wrote by saying: Otherwise at least one of the coordinate functions $z_1,...,z_n$ would be a nonconstant function when restricted to such a submanifold.

So far, because of the theorem to me, it makes sense to have $z_1, ..., z_n$ nonconstant since such a submanifold may not be connected. But, how this should imply their nonexistence?

Comment: Just work on a connected component. Each such must be a point.

Comment: This must have been asked already...

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that such a connected compact manifold $X$,  exists. Since $dimX>0$, it has two distinct points $u=(u_1,..,u_n); v=(v_1,...,v_n)$. There exists $i$ such that $u_i\neq v_i$, we deduce that $z_i(u)\neq z_i(v)$ contradiction since the restriction of $z_i$ to $X$ must be constant.

Comment: Did you mean compact?

Comment: yes, since the question is about compact complex manifolds

Comment: I don't see how do you make use of compactness

Comment: The compactness here is the theorem which says that the element of  $O(X)$ are constant if $X$ is compact, so contradiction since $z_i\in O(X)$ and is not constant.